# Exporting vs. returning a value

Tags: typescript, amd

Using TypeScript with AMD. Is it correct that

```
var name = "test";
return name;
```

and

```
var name = "test";
export = name;
```

do the same? Why was the "export = name" syntax created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `export =` statement you are declaring the externally visible member - whether that is a variable, function, class or module.

This does in fact get converted into a `return` statement in the transpiled JavaScript code - but it means more within the TypeScript type system - it says that the item being exported should replace the external module itself.

There is more on this in the [specification under 11.2.4 Export Assignments](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf)

Comment: Ok, I think I understood. Regarding runtime environment both statements do exactly the same. However, regarding coding environment the second variant makes the code, where those modules are imported, know about type of the imported module.

Comment: That's the idea - your TypeScript IDE will know that the "module" you are importing is actually a variable, not a module.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

> Export =
>
> TypeScript has built-in language support for external module loaders like CommonJS and AMD, which enables TypeScript to be used in environments like Node.js on the desktop and with libraries like require.js in the browser.  Both of these module systems provide the ability to provide an explicit value for the module.  For example, a ‘Client’ class may be set as the exported value from a module, allowing the ‘import’ to directly import the class.  TypeScript 0.9 now includes “export =” to support this use case

Cited from: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/06/18/announcing-typescript-0-9.aspx

I think you might be using that functionality wrong though, or am I missing something? In what context are you using this?